# Replace the elements in list of lists according to the indexes stored in another list

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, indexing

I have the following arrays:

```
example_array = [[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]]
indexes = [[1,2,3], [2,3], [0,4,2], [1,4,3], [0,4,3], [1,2,3], [1,2]]
```

I would like to replace the elements in the example_array with 1 according to the index in indexes. So, the expected result should be this:

```
example_array = [[0,1,1,1,0],[0,0,1,1,0],[1,0,1,0,1],[0,1,0,1,1],[1,0,0,1,1],[0,1,1,1,0],[0,1,1,0,0]].
```

I tried different approaches, for example to use pandas, like this:

```
matrix = pd.DataFrame(example_array)

for row in matrix:
    for i in indexes:
        for j in i:
            x_u.iloc[x, j] = 1
```

but it doesn't give me the hoped results! The solution does not need to use pandas library.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
example_array = [[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]]
indexes = [[1,2,3], [2,3], [0,4,2], [1,4,3], [0,4,3], [1,2,3], [1,2]]

for i,index in enumerate(indexes):
  for idx in index:
    example_array[i][idx] = 1
print example_array
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```or-tag-here
example_array = [[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]]
matrix = pd.DataFrame(example_array)
indexes = [[1,2,3], [2,3], [0,4,2], [1,4,3], [0,4,3], [1,2,3], [1,2]]
for row_num in range(len(matrix)):
    matrix.iloc[row_num][indexes[row_num]] = 1
```

It also saves you the nested loop!

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy array you can directly set specified indices to a desired value.

```
import numpy as np
example_array = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]])
indexes = [[1,2,3], [2,3], [0,4,2], [1,4,3], [0,4,3], [1,2,3], [1,2]]

for i, ind in enumerate(indexes):
    example_array[i, ind] = 1
print(a)
```

**Output**

```
[[0 1 1 1 0]
 [0 0 1 1 0]
 [1 0 1 0 1]
 [0 1 0 1 1]
 [1 0 0 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1 0]
 [0 1 1 0 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
example_array = [[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]];
indexes = [[1,2,3], [2,3], [0,4,2], [1,4,3], [0,4,3], [1,2,3], [1,2]];

for i in range(0, len(example_array)):
    for j in range(0, len(indexes[i])):
        example_array[i][indexes[i][j]] = 1;

print example_array;
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use the comprehension:

```
result = [[1 if i in ind else e for i, e in enumerate(ea)] for ea, ind in zip(example_array, indexes)]
```

Answer (score 1):

with a one liner:

```
indices = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [0, 4, 2], [1, 4, 3], [0, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2]]
print([[1 if idx in sub else 0 for idx in range(5)] for sub in indices])
```

output:

```
[[0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]]
```